# How to enumerate android version in res/values?

Tags: android

I made ​​two versions of the theme for my app.one for the android version below 4 and the second for the android version is greater than 4.

Placed them in res/values and res/values-v14.

Do I need to enumerate res/values-v15, res/values-v16 or res/values-v14-v15 ?

Comment: when u create res values-v11  mean its for api level 11 and above  same for level 14 and 15

Comment: May this helps you: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html

Answer (score 0):

Noope, res/vales-v14 applies to all version equal to or greater than 14, as per Android's documentation (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html):

> The API level supported by the device. For example, v1 for API level 1
>   (devices with Android 1.0 **or higher**) and v4 for API level 4 (devices
>   with Android 1.6 **or higher**).